# How to store a value of NSString as char array within a structure in Objective-C?

Tags: c, objective-c, struct, nsstring, char

I am having trouble assigning the value of an `NSString` to a `char *` within a structure of a singleton class. The following is a simplification of my problem. My code utilizes more fields in the structure and passes more `NSString`s.

Say I have a singleton class "SingletonClass" with a structure (I've done my homework with the Apple Documentation and implemented it correctly):

```
struct sampleStruct {
    char *string1;
    //other fields
} struct1;
```

with this method that sets the value of `struct1.string1` to the NSString that was passed:

```
- (void)initStructWithString:(NSString *)inputString {
     //warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
     struct1.string1 = [inputString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

and this method that uses `struct1.string1`:

```
- (void)useCharArray {
     //I would obviously be doing something more complex in reality
     printf("This is the char array: %s", struct1.string1);
     //doesn't print the value I assigned to it, but garbage
}
```

When I call `initStructWithString:(NSString *)inputString` from one class and try to call `useCharArray` from another class `struct1.string1` is a bunch of garbage. During debugging I've confirmed that each class is getting the same instance of this `SingletonClass`.

I'm still learning Objective-C as well as C along the way, so I'm aware it could be a problem with my memory management. I know I `[NSString cStringUsingEncoding]` should be assigned to a `const char *` and not a `char *`, but I don't know how else to go about it since the field in the structure is a `char *`. I've tried other approaches within `initSructWithString` such as assigning a new `const char *` the result of `[NSString cStringUsingEncoding]` and then copying that with `strlcpy` to `struct1.string1`. That approach had the same result.

What is the correct technique for storing the value of an `NSString` in a `char *` within a struct and how can I ensure that the fields within this struct retain their value as the `SingletonClass` is used by different classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing worth noting is that the correct method name would be `cStringUsingEncoding:`; and that this string disappears roughly at the same time `inputString` does, so the resulting string will have to be copied.

It might also be worth exploring the use of `UTF8String` instead (a convenience method that does the same).

Comment: Thanks for the correction and explanation. So when you say copy, am I looking at using memcpy since something like strlcpy will copy a pointer to a string that will disappear?

Comment: using memcpy is always a good idea; but you also need to allocate the target buffer before copying; so that you actually have some malloced memory to copy the string into.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet so writing here (after upping the above Answer)... Just came accross this (I realise it's a few years later) and figured an example might help others to some extent:

I'm using this to get the player's name from game center on iOS, I'll have issues with funky characters etc. but my font doesn't support them anyway. ppName is obviously a pointer to a pointer to a char, passed to the method I have this code in.

```
*ppName = (char *)malloc(strlen([pPlayer.alias UTF8String]));
strcpy(*ppName, [pPlayer.alias UTF8String]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store NSString in a struct, and then from that struct get an NSString back (for example if you needed to send a string to another player in a Game Center Multiplayer Game), you could do it like this :

```
typedef struct {
   char stringToSend[20];
   int stringToSendLength;
} myStruct;

// create a Struct and an NSString
myStruct aStruct;
NSString *stringToConvert = @"stringToConvert";

// convert NSString into char array
for (int i = 0; i < stringToConvert.length; i++) {
    aStruct.stringToSend[i] = [stringToConvert characterAtIndex:i];
}

aStruct.stringToSendLength = stringToConvert.length; // send string length

// store struct into NSData object
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&aStruct length:sizeof(myStruct)];

// retrieve data
myStruct *anotherStruct = (myStruct *)[data bytes];

// convert char array into NSString and only keep part required (without some weird random characters)
NSString *receivedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:anotherStruct->stringToSend length:anotherStruct->stringToSendLength encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```